# Load image when screen tapped

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tap

I'm attempting to make an app where you can tape to 'fire' and where you tap it will make an image appear aka a bullet hole. I realise I will have to make a `UIImageView` appear but I wouldn't have any idea how.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
   NSLog(@"X cord: %f",location.x);
   NSLog(@"Y cord: %f",location.y);
}
```

On above code you will get the current touch location.So place your image on that location.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your view `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
   [self addBulletHoleImageAtLocation:location];
}

-(void) addBulletHoleImageAtLocation:(CGPoint)location {
   UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, yourImageWidth, yourImageHeight)];
   imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bulletHole.png"];
   imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
   [self.view addSubview:imgView];
   [imgView release]; //if NON ARC
}
```

You can set different `contentMode` like, `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`, `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`as per your need.

Comment: A couple errors
- Use of undeclared identifiers 'yourImageWidth;
- No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView'
- ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
- 'release' iis unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

I'm assuming this is to do with my settings i had when i created my project, any way I can fix this?

Comment: **1)** You've to set the width and height of your bullet image in place of yourImageWidth and yourImageHeight. **2)** `[imgView release];` only need if your project is non ARC, it seems that its ARC, you should remove that line. **3)** `[self.view addSubView:imgView];` was typo mistake, it should `[self.view addSubview:imgView];` Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

    UIImage *bulletImg = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bullet.png"];
    UIImageView *bulletView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: bulletImg];

    int bulletWidth = bulletImg.size.width;
    int bulletHeight = bulletImg.size.height;

    bulletView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                  location.x - (bulletWidth / 2), // centered x position
                                  location.y - (bulletHeight / 2), // centered y position
                                  bulletWidth, // width
                                  bulletHeight // height
                                  );

    [self.view addSubview: bulletView];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view controller's view, and set it to perform an action/method where you show the image.

Comment: does it have to be a storyboard or can it be xib? and where do i add this?

Comment: @FjcymBlah Think you should start with some basics and learn Objective-C and iOS development

Comment: Im working on trying to teach myself, Ive done other forms of other ways of iOS Development but I havent used Objective-C in those ways of making iOS apps

Comment: Try reading a book, I don't think pasting some code in will help you at all

Comment: I know, It is helping but i cannot find a book